# Why can I open STMicroelectronics STLINK V2 with LibUSB, but not with STMicroelectronics Virutal COM Port

Tags: c, serial-port, usb, stm32, libusb

I have a LibUSB example in C++ code and I'm trying trying to connect `STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port` and I cannot connect it, even if I have the right `Vendor ID` and `Product ID`

But if I'm using my LibUSB example to connect `STMicroelectronics STLINK-V2`, then I can connect.

**Question:**

So why can LibUSB not connect to `STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port` with LibUSB, but I can connecto at `STMicroelectronics STLINK-V2`.

When I run this code snippet, `device_handle` returns `NULL` because `libusb` cannot connect when `vendorID = 1155, productID = 22336`. These numbers are for `STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port`.

```
device_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(ctx, vendorID, productID);
```

**Update:**

My goal is to connect my PC with my USB device so I can transfer and receive data from that USB device.

My operative system is Windows 11. There is nothing wrong with my USB device. I can connect it using QT C++ and transfer data to it. But not with libusb, it seems.

**Update 2:**

My USB device is a CDC - Communication Device Class.

Comment: Just a hint: is libusb able to connect to a CDC/ACM device? Or does it necessarily expect an HID device, as many "non-typed" device declare themselves?

Comment: @thebusybee I think LibUSB cannot connect a virtual COM Port. I have tried with `hidapi` library from `libusb` and even that library can't even connect to my STM32 Virtual COM Port. So I think I need to call internal WIN32 functions.

Comment: So this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you want to achieve? Of course you can open and process the port via standard file functions. But make sure to read at least some introduction.

Comment: @thebusybee I want to connect my PC to my USB device. But it seems that libusb cannot handle virtual com ports. Notice that my USB device is configured as a STM32 Virtual COM Port. I don't know why.

Comment: Yes, sure, but what do you want to do with the connected device? Does the device run your application or the bootloader? -- What OS are you using? -- Devices reveal themselves as specific devices. Your OS decides on this report (mostly on Linux) or the PID/VID combination (mostly on Windows), how to represent the device.

Comment: @thebusybee Windows 11, I want to send data and recieve data from my USB device. I know my Vendor and Product ID. My LibUSB library found the Vendor and Product ID of my STM32 Device and it's correct ID. vendorID = 1155, productID = 22336

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249796/discussion-between-the-busybee-and-heretic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, libusb cannot connect to just any USB device or interface; it can only connect to USB interfaces that have a specific driver attached to them that enables the kind of raw USB access that libusb needs.  One such driver is WinUSB (winusb.sys).

Your virtual serial port device is very likely using a different driver, like usbser.sys.  Therefore you cannot connect to it with libusb.  However, you could connect to it using the standard serial port functions in the Windows API, specifically: CreateFile, WriteFile, ReadFile, CloseFile, SetCommTimeouts, SetCommState.

Comment: usbser.sys.....you're damn right!

Comment: By the way. The only USB library that has been working for me is `QtSerialPort` from `QT C++`.

Comment: ...and Boost Asio.